# BigQuery: how can I determine if any of a set of elements is present in an array field?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery and SQL and I'm having trouble with a seemingly simple problem: one of the fields in the dataset I'm working with stores a json array in a field and I need to check whether any of a set of values is present in the json array for each row.

For example, say I have the following table:

```
id  json_array
1   ["foo", "bar", "fee"]
2   ["foo", "bar", "fee", "fum"]
3   ["fee", "fum"]
4   ["fum"]
```

And I'd like to create a new boolean field with the value `true` if either "foo" or "bar" are present in the array field and `false` otherwise:

```
id  json_array                     foo_bar_present
1   ["foo", "bar", "fee"]          True
2   ["foo", "bar", "fee", "fum"]   True
3   ["fee", "fum"]                 False
4   ["fum"]                        False
```

I've arrived at the following solution, but I have the nagging feeling that there has to be a better way:

```
SELECT 
id,
values,
(SELECT "foo" IN UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(values)))
OR
(SELECT "bar" IN UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(values))) AS foo_bar_present
FROM table
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479863/check-to-see-if-multiple-elements-in-bigquery-array

Comment: This 100% did the trick, thanks! I did search thoroughly for a similar question. Obviously I wasn't thorough enough!